Docker container path check fails
I am working on a python project and I need to create a docker image for testing.
The folder structure of my project is currently the following
|--main.py
|--parcellation_env.yml
|--module
|----__init__.py
|----config/
|------config_autoencoder.yaml
|------other_config_files
|----folder1
|------folder_1_files
|------folder_1_init
|----folder2
|------folder_2_files
|------folder_3 (which may contain other subfolders)...
|------folder_2_init
...

When running docker build . -t image_name the creation goes smoothly, but unfortunately when I try to run the docker container it gives an error. In particular, an assertion check fails because the os check for the autoencoder_config path fails. The dockerfile is as follows:
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY parcellation_env.yml .
RUN conda env create -f parcellation_env.yml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "parcellation_env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /app

COPY main.py /app/
ADD module/ /app/module/

ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "parcellation_env", "python", "/app/main.py", "-C", "/app/module/config/config_autoencoder.yaml", "--use-splits", "-y"]

I assume I got something wrong with the path of the config files, but since I'm new to docker, I do not get it.

Why not directly replace those two line COPY main.py /app/ and ADD module/ /app/module/ to COPY . /app/? This post is the difference between ADD and COPY.

So have you tried putting everything(folders/module/ etc) inside one folder let us call it "src" except your Dockerfile, then inside your dockerfile where you have ADD module/ /app/module/ change to ADD src/ /app PS: also add __init__.py inside your new src/ folder

@YuWeiLiu I tried what you suggested but unfortunately, it does not work. The purpose of not copying anything was that in the project folder there are also some working directories that I am not interested in having in the docker container

@DerekRoberts I can try, but please help me understand why I should put an __init__.py file in the src/, if the main.py is inside the src/ folder, why should I need an __init__.py file?

@Neskelogth sometimes python has an habit of not being able to resolve imports well. if you have vscode lets say you have a simple import such as from src.folder.class_1 import func1 (explanation-> click on src, inside the file, it will take you to the __init__.py file) now if you run python3 main.py without __init__.py inside that directory where main.py sits, it might find it difficult to find the func that is of interest hence you would have errors such as No module found error etc. it is a python weakness. Most times I run python -m src.module.file to have it behave from root dir/

Hi @Neskelogth let me know if this works, I am thinking if we can't achieve this maybe just invoke a script to help us but I am sure this would work I hope. please let me know many thanks ...

Sorry for the late answer, but apparently it is now working. The problem was most likely due to the path configuration (as suggested by the accepted answer) since when I changed it, it started working, but I am still not exactly sure how docker interpreted the path.
